# PyQt5 Selecting a row after insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Using PyQt5 with a QTableView, QStandardItemModel and QSortFilterProxy.  After doing an insertRow on the model the Sort Proxy displays the data in the View Table in the correct sort order; however, I need to issue a view.selectRow on the record that was just inserted.  Not sure how to do this if the ItemModel stores the data in unsorted order.

Similar but shorter example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QInputDialog


class Ui_Dialog(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(282, 247)
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(Dialog)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 192))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.tableModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tableModel.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableModel.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Category Name")
        self.tableProxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.tableProxy.setSourceModel(self.tableModel)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableProxy)
        self.tableProxy.setSortCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 210, 87, 29))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.setup_connections()
        self.load_data()
        self.tableProxy.sort(0)
        self.tableView.selectRow(0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "New"))

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_record)

    def load_data(self):
        data = ('Alpha', 'Charlie', 'Foxtrot', 'Zulu', 'Bravo', 'Tango')
        for ndx, val in enumerate(data):
            print(ndx, val)
            item = QStandardItem(val)
            self.tableModel.insertRow(ndx, item)

    def add_record(self):
        i, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Value Editor", "Emter A Value:")
        if ok:
            item = QStandardItem(i)
            self.tableModel.insertRow(self.tableModel.rowCount(), item)
            ### NEED TO TRIGGER TABLE TO SELECT THE ROW JUST INSERTED ###


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How is this not Mininal, Complete and Verifiable?

Comment: First please read the link, go point by point: the idea of complete is so that those who want to help you do not have to invest our time in patching code so that it can be executed, what you want is that your code can be copied, paste and execute, in your case it is not possible since there are things that are not defined as the .ui, in addition you do not show as instances CliDataBrowse, etc, the verifiable means that given your code you can verify that there is a problem and be the that you point out, but not having a complete code is impossible to verify,

Comment: [cont] and minimally refers to eliminating unnecessary things without losing the 2 previous qualities, does not necessarily refer to a small code because otherwise I put a line of code and would be minimum :-. Do you think your code meets all of the above? I do not think so. If you provide us with the foregoing we will try to provide you with a possible solution. I think you understand the positive thing that the OP provides a [mcve], your code is on the right track to do it but to improve it please to make it so.

Comment: what is `DataTable`?

Comment: Updated with a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

To select an item you must use the `selectionModel()` of the view, you have to pass the index of the model passed to the view, that is, the proxy, and the flag of the selection type. To obtain the index of the proxy you must first obtain the index of the sourceModel, for this you use `indexFromItem()` converting the `QStandardItem` to `QModelIndex`, and then use `mapFromSource()` to convert from the source to the proxy:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.tableModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tableModel.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableModel.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Category Name")
        self.tableProxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.tableProxy.setSourceModel(self.tableModel)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.tableProxy)
        self.tableProxy.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("New")
        self.setup_connections()
        self.load_data()
        self.tableProxy.sort(0)
        self.tableView.selectRow(0)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_record)

    def load_data(self):
        data = ('Alpha', 'Charlie', 'Foxtrot', 'Zulu', 'Bravo', 'Tango')
        for ndx, val in enumerate(data):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(val)
            self.tableModel.insertRow(ndx, item)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_record(self):
        i, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, "Value Editor", "Emter A Value:")
        if ok:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
            self.tableModel.insertRow(self.tableModel.rowCount(), item)
            ix = self.tableModel.indexFromItem(item)
            ix_proxy = self.tableProxy.mapFromSource(ix)
            self.tableView.selectionModel().select(ix_proxy, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```